# Question about using the same bed after divorce

Tags: halacha, marriage, divorce, sleep

Let's suppose a married couple have relations in a specific bed, then divorce and one of then (let's suppose the man), keeps the bed in his house after the divorce.

Can that man have relations with his second wife in the same bed that he had relations with his previous wife, as his previous wife may be offended, or he might remember her, or his new wife may feel uncomfortable?

Comment: Though some would argue that using the bed of a married couple is improper (cf. [Shab. 140b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.140b.4?with=all&lang=bi)) it is not halachically prohibited. Needless to say, Halachah isn’t the only factor in such a question and one must judge each case accordingly.

Comment: @eeerrrttt The question has been reopened based on the edits.

Comment: There is no problem. 100% allowed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the bed reminds the husband of his first wife and makes him think about her while with the 2nd wife, then he should not use that bed Nedarim 20b quoted in Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 240,2:

> ולא תתורו אחרי לבבכם מכאן אמר רבי אל ישתה אדם בכוס זה ויתן עיניו בכוס אחר אמר רבינא לא נצרכא אלא דאפילו ב' נשיו
>   "And you shall not be swayed after your heart"(Bamidbar 15,39) Rebbi said one should not drink from this cup and think about another cup (euphamism for wife see Ran:שבשעה שנזקק עם אשתו לא יתן עיניו באשה אחרת אפי' היא אשתו) Ravina says even if they are both his wives.

If every bed looks the same to him (most people probably share this view), and its his bed (if it belongs to the first wife he should give it back), and his second wife does not care about using the same bed (if she did care she would make sure he gets a new bed nowadays cheaply purchased), then he can use his own bed for his second marriage (his first wife should not be coming to his house checking on him).