# Changing husband's habits after remarrying

Tags: halacha, shalom-bayit, zivug-sheini

After remarrying, a husband inevitably keeps comparing the new wife to the former, no matter what was the reason for their separation (death or divorce), and that fact can undermine the ongoing Shlom Bayt and cause serious Hona'ah for the wife.

What do our sources say about changing the husband's habits in such a situation - like places (maybe the bedroom) or behaviors? Are there things he's obligated to change, or prescribed to change or good to change?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98534/question-about-using-the-same-bed-after-divorce?rq=1